# Is there a way to train an ML model to classify words into categories?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, coreml

I'm looking to train an ML model to classify words into several broad categories, in my case: color. So I'll have some pre-defined color buckets like these for example:

```
let blue = ["blue", "royal", "dark blue", "light blue"]
let red = ["red", "cardinal", "dusty red", "red polka dot"]
```

And I want

a) For the model to classify colors already existing in the buckets, i.e. if given "blue" it will know that "blue" is in the `blue` bucket.

b) For the model to take words not seen before, such as "faded blue", and to classify them in the correct bucket, in this case `blue` based on a confidence score of some sort.

I'm not sure if this is possible and the current method I have is a series of if statements to go about the classifying, but I'm wondering if there is a more intuitive way to do this with an ML model.

Comment: How would you want your model to classify 'purple'?

Comment: if you have enough data, it is possible, but you have to experiment. For example, you can use embeddings of words as input for training, or use the RGB values that represent the color to classify them.

Comment: @Justas I would have many more buckets than the two I listed in my code, I currently have around 15 buckets of different broad color categories with different values that qualify as that color. I think I have enough buckets that each color would theoretically have a corresponding bucket. So to answer your question, "purple" would fall into the `purple` bucket I have defined.

Comment: What would you do for yellow-green? Or any case like that?

Comment: @G.LC That's a good question, for my particular use case I'm assuming hybrid colors don't show up but I would probably go with the first color mentioned, so `yellow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try scikit-learn:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import  LogisticRegression


data = {'blue': ["blue", "royal", "dark blue", "light blue"],
        'red': ["red", "cardinal", "dusty red", "red polka dot"]}

train_data = pd.DataFrame(data).T.reset_index()
train_data.rename(columns={'index':'target'}, inplace=True)

# predictors
X = train_data.drop('target', axis=1)
X = X.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis=1)

# target
y = train_data.target

# simple toy model
clf  = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('vec',  CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2),)),
        ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])

# train a model
clf.fit(X,y)

# predict a new value
print(clf.predict(['faded blue']))
```

Hope this will set you to the right path :)

Results from above:
[image]